# Get Files and their directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter my files based on certain criteria and return a list of all items (including their parent directories)

Here is what I have for example

```
get-childitem ./ -Recurse -Filter "*&*" | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -Propety Name
```

This does return all of files I want in this format

- File 1.txt
- File 2.txt
- File 3.txt

I was wondering if there would be a way to have them dislay like this:

- Folder 1/Folder 2/File1.txt
- Folder 3/File 2.txt
- Folder 3/Folder 4/File 3.txt

The folders are in no particular order or layout, so I would just like to get the full path of the file.

Comment: Does the `FullName` property do what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just select the `FullName`

```
get-childitem ./ -Recurse -Filter "*&*" | 
        ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
        Select-Object -Property FullName
```

Comment: typo: "-Propety" should be "-Property" on last line.

Comment: Whats about Directory and File switch in Powershell 3.0?